# Desktop flickers on Ubuntu 18.04 after Wake up from Suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, intel-graphics

I take care of two Lenovo laptops (T470 and X230) with Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed on both and both with Intel graphics. Both show flickering Gnome desktops after wake-up from Suspend to RAM since one or two weeks. Can't start any application anymore.

Workaround is to [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F1] and log-in again. Any idea how to fix it or what causes it?

Comment: I am on a Thinkpad X1 Yoga 1st gen and also have this issue. Hitting the lock button on top right menu also triggers it. Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: I have this too, I'm fairly sure it's a bug introduced by a recent update to either Gnome or Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I figured I'm not the only one. I have a third ubuntu laptop (E480) from Lenovo with Ubuntu installed. I will check this week if the error occurs there too.

Comment: The latest update fixed this for me.

Comment: Problem seems to be fixed here too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's worked for me (Lenovo G50-80 i3 Intel graphics):

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   i.e. change to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
   ```
3. Save and close the file.
4. Update GRUB:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot.

Comment: What about `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`?